# Which Platform/Language to use for heavy computing/ML tasks?

Tags: python, machine-learning, go, rust, julia

We have built an MVP in Python Data ecosystem, but the performance is much less than desired.

Our approach:

- multiprocessing module for task parallelisation (which is awkwardly done in Python - pickle/unpickle each task)
- scikit-learn library
- pandas for data transport
- it's not about dealing with big data or training models on large data, after profiling we figured out most of the time is taken by a regular computing tasks, but we are doing a lot.

Hence:

1. We wonder what else can we use to make computing faster? After some research number of candidates popped up: Julia, Lua, Rust etc.

   - Requirements:

     - FASTER
     - Parallelisation support by design (not some workaround like Python does)
     - Existence of scientific libraries, not all of Python but major selection
     - Compiled (I guess)
2. But before we move to another platform - we wonder if there's a way of speeding up existing Python code?